# Why does this refactored ruby method return nil?

Tags: ruby, arrays, time, refactoring, null

I wrote a method in class Float which takes a float (seconds) and converts it into a countdown timer. The code works fine when I write it like this:

```
class Float
  def to_countdown
    (self % 60) == 1 ? cd_sec = "#{(self % 60).to_i} second" : ( (self % 60).to_i == 0 ? cd_sec = "" : cd_sec = "#{(self % 60).to_i} seconds" )
    ((self/60) % 60) == 1 ? cd_min = "#{((self/60) % 60).to_i} minute" : ( ((self/60) % 60).to_i == 0 ? cd_min = "" : cd_min = "#{((self/60) % 60).to_i} minutes" )
    (self/3600) == 1 ? cd_hour = "#{(self/3600).to_i} hour" : ( (self/3600).to_i == 0 ? cd_hour = "" : cd_hour = "#{(self/3600).to_i} hours" )
    (self/(60*60*24)) == 1 ? cd_day = "#{(self/(60*60*24)).to_i} day" : ( (self/(60*60*24)).to_i == 0 ? cd_day = "" : cd_day = "#{(self/(60*60*24)).to_i} days" )
    countdown = [cd_day, cd_hour, cd_min, cd_sec].reject! {|c| c == nil}
    return countdown.to_sentence
  end
end

509330.546146.to_countdown => "x days, y hours, z minutes, and a seconds"
```

I wanted to refactor it. My end results was:

```
class Float
  def to_countdown
    s,m,h,d = (self % 60),((self/60) % 60),((self/3600)%24),(self/(60*60*24))
    s == 1 ? cd_sec  = "#{s.to_i} second" : ( s.to_i == 0 ? cd_sec  = "" : cd_sec  = "#{s.to_i} seconds" )
    m == 1 ? cd_min  = "#{m.to_i} minute" : ( m.to_i == 0 ? cd_min  = "" : cd_min  = "#{m.to_i} minutes" )
    h == 1 ? cd_hour = "#{h.to_i} hour"   : ( h.to_i == 0 ? cd_hour = "" : cd_hour = "#{h.to_i} hours" )
    d == 1 ? cd_day  = "#{d.to_i} day"    : ( d.to_i == 0 ? cd_day  = "" : cd_day  = "#{d.to_i} days" )
    countdown = [cd_day, cd_hour, cd_min, cd_sec].reject! {|c| c == nil}
    return countdown.to_sentence
  end
end
```

When I try the refactorized version, I get:

```
509330.546146.to_countdown => **undefined method `to_sentence' for nil:NilClass>.**
```

which means that `countdown` is `nil`. What did I do wrong in the refactored version?

Comment: You could further refactor those lines like this `cd_sec = s==1 ? "#{s.to_i} second" : (s.to_i == 0 ? "" : "#{s.to_i} seconds" )`

Comment: Don't give the code and try the reader to guess. Rather give what the input and the expected outputs are.

Comment: Sorry will edit my code to show both!

Comment: While Sergio's `compact` is the better option in this case, note you can do things like `reject!(&:nil?) instead of including a block and doing an explicit compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this

```
countdown = [cd_day, cd_hour, cd_min, cd_sec].reject! {|c| c == nil}
```

with this

```
countdown = [cd_day, cd_hour, cd_min, cd_sec].compact
```

Also, you're using bang version. It mutates the array in-place and [can return nil](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-reject-21). If you want to keep using `reject`, use a regular version (non-bang).

Comment: Thank you very much! This solved my problem. Was it such an obvious answer that I got down-voted for it?

Comment: @SeanLarkin: Probably somebody thought so. You're returning the result of `reject!`, so most people's first thought would be to look at the docs for `reject!`, which states that it returns `nil` if the array wasn't changed. But don't let it get you down. When you're new, you're new.

Comment: Fair enough! I appreciate the insight. I'm just a believer that if you are going to down-vote, explain why so that humans (who make mistakes) can correct and learn from them, and therefore couldn't help but ask.